# How to display value on based kendo template?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-template

Here is my code.

```
<span ng-show="#: Reading #">HI</span>&nbsp;<span>#: UOM #</span>
```

And my expectation is to show msg 'HI' when 'Reading' data is not null. But actually it displays only for Integer data not for Alphabetical data. but i need to display for both number and alphabetical data. please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the Boolean() function, like this:

```
<span ng-show="#: Boolean(Reading) #">HI</span>&nbsp;<span>#: UOM #</span>
```